# Animated svg in Flutter

Tags: flutter, svg, flutter-animation, vector-graphics, svg-animate

I have tried to render an animated SVG image in my Flutter application, but unfortunately, I couldn't achieve it. Since mostly static SVG images can be rendered using packages like [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg), etc else we can animate the rendered SVG image like rotate, and some other animation types.

But I have an animated SVG image, I just need to render the image in my Flutter app. And I checked on several packages like [rive](https://pub.dev/packages/rive), etc. In those I need to convert to riv format, and in a few package JSON format is supported. I don't want to convert my animated SVG image to any other format. Are there any packages that just render animated SVG images which we do not need to convert to any other formats?

I have attached my sample [animated SVG image](https://easyupload.io/9gcjgk). This link is valid for 30 days.